email brokerage tool
I'm thinking about using civi for a project, but the project requires an email brokerage tool
Essentially this means I'd need:

a user to fill out a form stating their requirements (with maybe a multi select field for (let's say) "skills" to list the skills they require.

System automatically finds contacts with the required skills and sends a (bulk?) email to them (bulk is preferable for tracking, but not essential).


I've been thinking that maybe this could be done with scheduled reminders (if an activity is sparked by the original form submission) but there's no infrastructure for building a smart group or search 'on the fly's.
Another thought was maybe programmatically conducting a search and triggering a bulk email (but not sure if that's needed, or how to go about it, yet).
This is a wordpress site.
If anyone has any suggestions or ideas of where to start for an easy way to do this, please do throw it at me!
Many thanks in advance...


there's no infrastructure for building a smart group or search 'on the fly's.

Actually, now there is! You can enable the "Scheduled Communications" extension (bundled with core) which allows you to use SearchKit as the basis of your scheduled reminder.

I like the sound of that... I'll look into it. Thanks Coleman. Much appreciate your time :)
